# Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following

Tags: function, plsql, package

when i run my sql code i get the following error
Errors: PACKAGE POS
Line/Col: 14/5 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

current delete exists prior

Below is the code
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pos
AS
FUNCTION insert_in_products(
prod_id NUMBER,
prod_name VARCHAR2,
price NUMBER
) RETURN VARCHAR2;

```
FUNCTION insert_in_customers(
    cust_id NUMBER,
    first_name VARCHAR2,
    last_name VARCHAR2,
    email VARCHAR2,
) RETURN VARCHAR2;
```

END pos;
/

I wrote the similiar code for body also and it showed the same error. The code was working fine when I added only the first function.

Please help me with the code

Comment: You have an extra comma after your last parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the last comma. It should look like this:

```
FUNCTION insert_in_customers(
cust_id NUMBER,
first_name VARCHAR2,
last_name VARCHAR2,
email VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2;
```